# How do I call for a modal window when clicking a date in an inline Jquery Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, modal-dialog

I've been searching for a solution to this for a while, and I'm a bit of a Javascript noob, so I'm having trouble writing around the issue myself.

I've got an inline datepicker that is identifying dates with "events" using `beforeShowDay` to paint alternate CSS styles. My trouble is trying to produce a modal popup when a user clicks one of these specific dates. Here is the code I have:

```
<div style="display:none" id="dialog-modal">
        <h1>This is dialog content</h1>
    </div>

$("#datepicker").datepicker({beforeShowDay: highlightEvents, onSelect: showEvent});

        function highlightEvents(date) {
            var events = new Array(<cfoutput>#ValueList(EventDetailOutput.days)#</cfoutput>);
            var day = date.getDate();
            if ($.inArray(day, events) == -1) return [true,""];
            return [true, "eventDate"];

        }

        function showEvent(date) {
            var events = new Array(<cfoutput>#ValueList(EventDetailOutput.days)#</cfoutput>);
            var day = date.getDate();
            if ($.inArray(day, events) == -1) {
                $(function() {
                    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({modal: true});
                });
            }

        }
```

I was hoping to look at my array in the same way I was in my `highlightEvents` function and produce a modal window upon select.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: It basically does nothing - it adds a # to my url and puts me at the top of the page as if there were an anchor up there.

I think the problem is where I set `var day` in the second function. It seems that `date.getDate()` isn't working in `showEvent`. It works fine in `highlightEvents` and it passes in `date` correctly. I can alert the values of `date` and my array, `events`, but if I alert `day` I get an error in firebug that says the function does not exist.